# Ansible, windows - how to access network folder?

Tags: security, ansible, kerberos, delegation, winrm

I want to use Ansible to automate my deployment process. Let me say few words about it. Deployment process in my case consists of two steps:

- update DB (SQL Script)
- copy predefined set of files to various network folders (on different machines)

For this purpose I use special selfwritten program called Installer.exe. If I run it myself it performes operations with my credentials. So it has all my rights, e.g. access to network folders and SQL Databese.
[image]
I want to use Ansible as wrapper for my program (Installer.exe), not instead of it. My target scenario - Ansible prepares configuration files and runs my installer on remote windows machine. I've faced a problem - **my program run by Ansible hasn't my full rights**. It can successfully access SQL Database 1 on the same machine, but can't access SQL Database 2 on remote machine or access network folder. I always get "access denied" on networks access, SQL Database says something about NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON. **It looks like double hop problem**, but not exactly it as far as I understand it. Double hop is about service accounts, but I am trying to access remote server with my own personal accouns.

**UPD 1**:
My variables for that group are:

```
ansible_user: qtros@ABC.RU
ansible_port: 5986
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
ansible_winrm_operation_timeout_sec: 120
ansible_winrm_read_timeout_sec: 150
ansible_winrm_transport: kerberos
ansible_winrm_kerberos_delegation: yes
```

Before any actions with Ansible I run the following command:

```
$> kinit qtros@ABC.RU
```

and enter my password. Later if run klist I can see some valid tickets. I intended to use domain account, but not local system account. Am I doing it right?

**UPD 2**: if I add such command in playbook:

```
...
raw: "klist"
...
```

I get something like:

```
fatal: [targetserver.abc.ru]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "failed": true, "rc": 1, "stderr": "", "stdout": "\r\nCurrent LogonId is 0:0x20265db4\r\nError calling API LsaCallAuthenticationPackage (ShowTickets substatus): 1312\r\n\r\nklist failed with 0xc000005f/-1073741729: A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.\r\n\r\n\r\n", "stdout_lines": ["", "Current LogonId is 0:0x20265db4", "Error calling API LsaCallAuthenticationPackage (ShowTickets substatus): 1312", "", "klist failed with 0xc000005f/-1073741729: A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.", "", ""]}
```

Comment: Having the same issue. When trying to access network folders I get access denied. 
Also: win_command: whoami shows the proper domain user that I set for ansible_user, and while win_command: 'net use s: //some.server.name/a_network_folder /user:domain\username password' gives out "done successfully " running win_command: net use shows drive s: as "unavailable". 
Did you manage to solve this issue? How?

Answer (score 3):

Based on your problem statement, it sounds like the Windows machine is running installer.exe under the Local System account, which has no rights outside of the Windows machine itself and will always fail trying to run any procedure on SQL Database 2.  This wouldn't be a Kerberos double-hop scenario.  For one, there's only one hop between the Windows machine in the middle of the diagram running installer.exe and SQL Database 2.  Since your Ansible program is wrapping up installer.exe inside of it, then unless I'm missing something, run the Ansible program on the Windows machine with AD domain credentials having the appropriate rights to SQL Database 2.

EDIT:  As the focus of your question was based on resolving the SQL Database 2 message regarding NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON, and whether or not this was a Kerberos double hop problem (doesn't look like it), that's what I answered on.  Note you have ansible_user defined but not ansible_ssh_pass.  There's an apparent bug in the documentation (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_windows.html), so use  ansible_ssh_pass instead of ansible_ssh_password.

Comment: I intended to use domain accoung, but not sure if I do it right. I've updated my question, can you see 'UPD 1' section?

Comment: I've tried all possible combinations with/without ansible_user/ansible_ssh_pass and no luck. Updated post again.

Comment: Seems that 'ansible_ssh_pass' doesn't have any effect since I use 'ansible_winrm_transport: kerberos'. Do you agree? I also noted that from target server I even can't accrss my own shared folders: \\qtros\share, but can access shared folders of targetserver: \\targetserver\share. Where is my mistake? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On your statement: "Seems that 'ansible_ssh_pass' doesn't have any effect since I use 'ansible_winrm_transport: kerberos'."  I agree.  With Kerberos, passwords would not be passed over the network nor would they need to be saved inside configuration files.  Now, can you clarify what does this mean:  "I also noted that from target server I even can't accrss my own shared folders"?

Comment: I mean that from "Some machine" I can't access \\qtros\<shared folder>. It's my own shared folders and I am logged in to "Some machine" via Ansible with my credentials. It is very surprising that I have no access to my own machine with my credentials.